# Requests received as null on server

Tags: ios, .net, iis, networking, load-balancing

Requests from iOS are being sent filled from the app but received as null on the server and it is random, sometimes the same request is received correct, and sometimes it is received as null, other channels (android and web) are not facing this issue
to note that the front-end connects to a load-balancer (layer 7) that redirects the requests to one of the 3 nodes, and the issue is happening on the 3 nodes, the traffic on the WAF and the load-balancer seems normal, we installed a new SSL certificate in feb, but i don't think it is related
we tried to simulate the case on the dev environment with the same application and the server server (code and infrastructure) and it did not happen

i am stuck here, and unable to identify the reason of such a behavior on production

any suggestions?

Comment: check differences between IOS post and Android (log them), then review AppTransportSecurity  in your Info.plist (may be related to SSL).

Comment: What is "received as null"? You have to provide more information. Also depending on whether you can reproduce this frequently, capture the actual network packets (by disabling SSL) and analyze them. More hints can be found in that way.

Comment: @LexLi the request object is received as null, i disabled the check the SSL on the iOS and i am getting the same

Comment: What I said is to ask you analyze the issue (differences) at HTTP packet level. If you don't know how to do that, the search engines have tons of guides.